# Email Validation in Grails

Tags: validation, grails

Is there a way in grails to define an email field which is nullable, but if the value is present, then it must be of type email?

I tried

```
String name
String email

static constraints = {
    email nullable: true, blank: false, email: true
}
```

but if I don't provide any value for email and only the value for name, the instance is not saved.

Answer (score 1):

Check email parameter. Maybe it is not null but a blank string. In this case it would fail because of "blank:false" constraint.

Comment: Ok, so how do I define such a case where it's ok to have null but if there's a value it must be an email?

Answer (score 1):

After reading your question I understand you require that name and email are provided, assuming that your domain class has the name Profile you could try this:

```
class Profile {
    String name
    String email

    static constraints = {
        name blank: false
        email nullable: false, blank: false, email: true
    }
}
```

You could then check if the save method returns null, indicating that there is a validation error and as a result the instance is not persisted. You can read about this here http://docs.grails.org/snapshot/ref/Domain%20Classes/save.html

I try this when app is starting, here you can see email property in profile1 and profile2 are not valid values, so are not persisted, it is verified if the email value is the cause and if so, a message is written

```
package demo

class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->
        Profile profile1 = new Profile(name: 'john', email: '')
        Profile profile2 = new Profile(name: 'peter', email: 'asdasd')
        Profile profile3 = new Profile(name: 'ana', email: 'ana@example.com')

        List<Profile> profiles = [profile1, profile2, profile3]

        profiles.each { Profile profile ->
            if (!profile.save()) {
                if (profile.errors.hasFieldErrors('email')) {
                    println profile.errors.getFieldError('email').rejectedValue + ' is an invalid values'
                }
            }
        }
    }

    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

Here the output is

```
grails> rA
| Running application...
null is an invalid values
asdasd is an invalid values
Grails application running at http://localhost:8080 in environment: development
grails>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove `blank: false` This creates conflict between `nullable` & `blank` property. Then you can save data without email if null, otherwise email type will be verified.